# How do I project content from an angular component in a child route to a slot in a parent component?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an app that's composed of nested components rendered through child routes. What I'd like to be able to do is project content from a component at the lowest level in the route hierarchy into a slot in the parent or grandparent component as shown in the illustration below.

Ideally I'd prefer to avoid creating distinct components for the "widgets" owned by Tab 1, but rather I'd like to define that content inline in the template for Tab 1 in an `<ng-template>` for example. Reason is, the content of those widgets would be intrinsically linked to the content of Tab 1 (with different content for Tab 2 etc). I found a few similar questions to this on SO but none that quite seemed to match what I'm after so apologies if the solution is already out there and I've missed it. Even a steer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Illustration of required outcome]

Comment: If you are able to share the exact same data between these components will that satisfy your need ?

Comment: I'm afraid not - if I've understood you correctly anyway. The content in those widgets will be a variety of form controls that are logically part of the Tab 1 component, it's just that the design calls for them to be physically outside the bounds of the router-outlet that contains the lowest level page. Think of them as something like a toolbar that changes contextually with the active content in the tabbed page. I want to be able to push markup as well as data from the child component to the parent.

Comment: can you not toggle it with knowing the current route ?